# How jwt token get reissued in azure ad OuthImplicitFlow

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, adal

Currently the scenario is. When I am trying to access my app,it first sends my app to Microsoft login page and after successful login it returns a id token which is used to retrieve the data from backend server. Now the expiry time of token is approx 1 hr. Now when this token expires, Microsoft issues a new token(JWT Token), it not redirects me back to login page.
 But ideally it should be redirected to login page, as in implicit flow, there is no refresh token. Then on what basis it is issuing a new token ?
I am using Microsoft adal library in my front end side for authentication.

Comment: It works based on silent renew feature.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit in detail. Or can you provide a link for that?

Comment: @Tapesh Gupta Same as you described the ID token expires after 30 mins to 1 hour. My problem is I am not able to access backend resource after expiry of token, even though we are still signed in. Does that mean I am not getting new JWT token? Any suggestions on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#refreshing-tokens

> The implicit grant does not provide refresh tokens. Both id_tokens and
>   access_tokens will expire after a short period of time, so your app
>   must be prepared to refresh these tokens periodically. To refresh
>   either type of token, you can perform the same hidden iframe request
>   from above using the prompt=none parameter to control the identity
>   platform's behavior. If you want to receive a new id_token, be sure to
>   use id_token in the response_type and scope=openid, as well as a nonce
>   parameter.

Comment: Is there any way, we can prevent getting this token refreshed, so that we can send user to Microsoft login page ?

Comment: I think there should be a cookie in the browser that is responsible for that, you can clear that cookie, then you won't be able to auto refresh the token. another way would be doing a logout

Comment: actually,might be easier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request. prompt=login

Comment: Your app needs to *not* refresh the token then. And prompt=login is a good way to force re-login. But why do you want to force re-login? Users having to enter their password constantly is not a good thing. It makes them less likely to see phishing attempts.

Comment: I was not sure, whether it was ok to get the new token without getting user sign in again. Thanks for help.